# JQuery Element change in Repeatable Form Sections

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, formidable

OK, so I am using a plugin called Formidable forms which offers a feature to create repeatable sections in a form (which is awesome, btw). What I'm trying to do is affect all the sections of fields the same. When you make a section repeatable, it creates a "name" identifier with the following layout example - name="item_meta[143][0][153]" - where the [0] is the first section. Then the next section contains a [1], next has a [2], and so on.

So, I am trying to modify the total field for each section with some custom math. I got it to work for the first section, but for the following sections, I need to find an automatic way target those following sections with the [i] selector.

I tried to do this with a loop, but I think something might be wrong with my logic. Anyway, here's what I got

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
for (i=0; i < $(".frm_field_153_container input").length; i++){
$('input[name="item_meta[145][i][153]"]').change(function(){
var val1 = $("input[name='item_meta[145][i][153]']").val();
var val2 = $("select[name='item_meta[145][i][144]']").val();
var cost = val2.substring(val2.indexOf("$")+1);
console.log(cost);
if (val1 >=24 && val1 <= 47) {
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost-3) * val1).toFixed(2));
console.log(newcost);
$("[name='item_meta[145][i][154]']").val(newcost);}
if (val1 >=48 && val1 <= 71) {
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost-5) * val1).toFixed(2));
console.log(newcost);
$("[name='item_meta[145][i][154]']").val(newcost);}
if (val1 >=72 && val1 <= 143) {
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost-6) * val1).toFixed(2));
console.log(newcost);
$("[name='item_meta[145][i][154]']").val(newcost);}
if (val1 >=144 && val1 <= 287) {
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost-7) * val1).toFixed(2));
console.log(newcost);
$("[name='item_meta[145][i][154]']").val(newcost);}
if (val1 >=288) {
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost-8) * val1).toFixed(2));
console.log(newcost);
$("[name='item_meta[145][i][154]']").val(newcost);}
});
}
});
</script>
```

The page is live at www.highschoolimpressions.com/order-form/ - (it's on page 2, so go to the bottom and click the "Next" button to see this form part).

Thanks

Comment: The page http://www.highschoolimpressions.com/order-form/ is no longer accessible. So, unfortunately, no chance of improving my answer any further ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find DOM elements on the basis of your variable `i` then you need to do something like the following:

```
$('input[name="item_meta[145]['+i+'][153]"]')
```

since otherwise the `i` inside `$('input[name="item_meta[145][i][153]"]')` would be interpreted just as the letter 'i' and nothing else.

Once you have found this element you can use its reference `this` inside your `.change()` method like this (you don't have to search it again):

```
$('input[name="item_meta[145]['+i+'][153]"]').change(function(){
var val1 = $(this).val();
...
```

Indeed the whole loop can be written much simpler in jquery style as

```
$(".frm_field_153_container input").change(function(){
var val1 = $(this).val();
...
```

This will bind the `.change()` method to all of your found input fields. The rest of the code of course also needs to be looked at in order to replace the now obsolete `i`s with suitable relative traverse-expressions to find the other related DOM elements.

Comment: @RBizzle: Could you provide some snippets of your generated form? I have the feeling that the whole operation could be done with a much simpler (and more easy to maintain) code.

Comment: I pretty much abandoned the idea of using a loop to go through and do this an infinite amount of times. I ended up just reiterating the code 4 times with different variables and class assignments for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going this route and abandoning the idea of looping through.

```
// ----------  Product Number 1   ---------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Assign consistent classes to necessary form elements
var productIDSelect = jQuery('select[id^="field_productid"]');
    productIDSelect.attr('class', function (index) {
    return 'productid-' + index;
});
var totalQuantField = jQuery('input[id^="field_totalquant"]');
    totalQuantField.attr('class', function (index) {
    return 'prodtotalquant-' + index;
});
var costEachField = jQuery('input[id^="field_prodcosteach"]');
    costEachField.attr('class', function (index) {
    return 'prodcosteach-' + index;
});
var totalCostField = jQuery('input[id^="field_prodtotalcost"]');
    totalCostField.attr('class', function (index) {
    return 'prodtotalcost-' + index;
});
var prodEPLApplyCheck = jQuery('input[id^="field_eplapply"]');
    prodEPLApplyCheck.attr('class', function (index) {
    return 'prodeplapply-' + index;
});
    // If any of these fields get changed, perform this recalculate function
jQuery('.prodtotalquant-0, .productid-0, .prodeplapply-0, #field_indnamenum-1, #field_indnamenum-2, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0, #field_sleevefirst-0, #field_sleevesecond-0').change(function(){
    // Get the total quantity of garments input by the user
var val1 = jQuery('.prodtotalquant-0').val();
    // Get the value associated with the selected garment (string)
var val2 = jQuery('.productid-0').val();
    // Get the Base Cost of the Garment (convert val2 to a valid number value
var cost = parseFloat(val2.substring(val2.indexOf("$")+1));
    // If Individual Name on back is desired, then apply charge
if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-1').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
    cost=cost+6;
}
    // If Individual Number on back is desired, then apply charge
if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-2').is(':checked')  && jQuery('prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
    cost=cost+6;
}
//---------------Begin Actual Calculations ----------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Base Minimum Quantity Validating
if (val1 <=11){
        cost="Must Order at least 12";
    }
    //Begin Stepping through the pricing break points and checking for extra print locations
    //Step 1 - Minimum
if (val1 >=12 && val1 <= 23) {
    //Check for Back Prints
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-1, #field_indnamenum-2, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost+4;
        console.log(cost);
    } else {
        console.log(cost);
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
    //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+4;  
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+4;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat(((cost) * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
    //Step 2
if (val1 >=24 && val1 <= 47) {
    //Check for Back Prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-0, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost;
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost-3).toFixed(2);}
        //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+3;  
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+3;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat((cost * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
    //Step 3
if (val1 >=48 && val1 <= 71) {
    //Check for Back Prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-0, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost-2.5;
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost-5).toFixed(2);}
        //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+2.5;    
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+2.5;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat((cost * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
    //Step 4
if (val1 >=72 && val1 <= 143) {
        //Check for Back Prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-0, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost-4;

    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost-6).toFixed(2);}
        //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+2;  
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+2;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat((cost * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
    //Step 5
if (val1 >=144 && val1 <= 287) {
    //Check for Back Prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-0, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost-5.5;
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost-7).toFixed(2);}
        //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+1.5;    
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+1.5;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat((cost * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
    //Step 6 - Final
if (val1 >=288) {
    //Check for Back Prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_indnamenum-0, #field_roster-0, #field_roster-1, #field_classsign-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = cost-7;
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost-8).toFixed(2);}
        //Check for sleeve prints and apply charge
    if (jQuery('#field_sleevefirst-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
        cost = parseFloat(cost)+1;  
        //Check for second sleeve print and apply charge
        if (jQuery('#field_sleevesecond-0').is(':checked') && jQuery('.prodeplapply-0').is(':checked')) {
            cost = parseFloat(cost)+1;
        }
    } else {
        cost = parseFloat(cost).toFixed(2);}
jQuery('.prodcosteach-0').val(cost);
var newcost = parseFloat((cost * val1).toFixed(2));
jQuery('.prodtotalcost-0').val(newcost);
}
})
});
```